# Oracle how to get most common value in a column for multiple columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have the following table, how can I group by ID, and get the most common value in each column
p.s. table is big, and I need to do this for many columns

```
ID  Col1  Col2  Col3....
1   A     null
1   A     X
1   B     null
1   A     Y
2   C     X
2   C     Y
2   A     Y
3   B     Z
3   A     Z
3   A     Z
3   B     X
3   B     Y
```

Expected result:

```
ID  Col1  Col2  Col3....
1   A     null
2   C     Y
3   B     Z
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way, using analytic functions and `keep`:

```
select id,
       min(col1) keep(dense_rank first order by cnt_col1 desc) as col1_mode,
       min(col2) keep(dense_rank first order by cnt_col2 desc) as col2_mode,
       min(col3) keep(dense_rank first order by cnt_col3 desc) as col3_mode
from (select id,
             count(*) over (partition by id, col1) as cnt_col1,
             count(*) over (partition by id, col2) as cnt_col2,
             count(*) over (partition by id, col3) as cnt_col3
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

The most frequent value is called the "mode" in statistics, and Oracle offers a function to calculate this.  So, an easier way is to use `stats_mode()`:

```
   select id,
         stats_mode(col1) as mode_col1,
         stats_mode(col2) as mode_col2,
         stats_mode(col3) as mode_col3
  from table t
  group by id;
```

EDIT:

As noted in a comment, `stats_mode()` does not count `NULL` values.  The easiest way to fix this is to find some value that is not in the data and do:

```
   select id,
          stats_mode(coalesce(col1, '<null>')) as mode_col1,
          stats_mode(coalesce(col2, '<null>')) as mode_col2,
          stats_mode(coalesce(col3, '<null>')) as mode_col3
  from table t
  group by id;
```

The other way is to revert to the first approach or something similar:

```
select id,
       (case when sum(case when col1 = mode_col1 then 1 else 0 end) >= sum(case when col1 is null then 1 else 0 end)
             then mode_col1
             else NULL
        end) as mode_col1,
       (case when sum(case when col2 = mode_col2 then 1 else 0 end) >= sum(case when col2 is null then 1 else 0 end)
             then mode_col2
             else NULL
        end) as mode_col2,
       (case when sum(case when col3 = mode_col13 then 1 else 0 end) >= sum(case when col3 is null then 1 else 0 end)
             then mode_col3
             else NULL
        end) as mode_col3
from (select t.*,
             stats_mode(col1) over (partition by id) as mode_col1,
             stats_mode(col2) over (partition by id) as mode_col2,
             stats_mode(col3) over (partition by id) as mode_col3
      from table t
     ) t
group by id;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, The result doesn't meet on `NULL` values.

Comment: Should that not be `stats_mode(...) over (partition by col1)`?

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger . . . `stats_mode()` can be either an aggregation function or an analytic function.

Comment: @ajmalmhd04 . . . Really good point.  Alternatives edited in.